# Strange Spree Login Issue - Possibly cookie, browser, NGINX related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, nginx, spree

We are currently having a very strange issue that is occurring with a Spree install running on NGINX.  Users are reporting issues recovering passwords and once recovered having issues of logging into the site.  We have not been able to reproduce this error but know it is certainly happening due to all of the reports from users we are receiving.  Also to not is users are able to login when they try a different browser.  If the first attempt is in Firefox and then they try Chrome chrome will end up working in a good amount of cases.

**Email from user:**
"Still not getting through to shop. I have changed my password twice now and when I got to put it in nothing happens. It just refreshes the page and I am left with a blank spot for e-mail and password. "

**Errors in the NGINX error log:**

```
cache: [GET /login] miss
cache: [POST /user/sign_in] invalidate, pass
```

**Configuration:**
Rails 3.1, Spree 1, passenger-3.0.11, ruby 1.8.7 REE

Any and all answers / suggestions are GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two rails applications were running on both a domain and a subdomain and the browser had conflicts with the session cookie set in the file session_store.rb that had the same key and would not allow users to login if they had the cookie from sample-domain.com first or shop.sample-domain.com respectively.